# How do I make a sprite rotate around another moving sprite?

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics, physics, game-development

I am currently making a game and I want to add a power up. I am essentially trying to make something similar to the spell book from Castlevania. I found a code to help me get the initial position and rotation. The problem is, the cross doesn't move from it's initial location. It just circles in place while the other one leaves it. I am still new to pygame and the math that goes with game dev. It is still pretty confusing.

```py
import pygame

class Crucifix(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                self.sprite = pygame.image.load('image'). convert_alpha()
                
                self.image = self.sprite 
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.x =500
                self.rect.y = 500
                self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
               
                
        def update(self):
            self.rect.x -= 2
            if self.rect.x == -100:
                self.kill()
            
class EnemiesStrong(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)     
        self.original_image = pygame.image.load('image').convert_alpha()
        self.image = self.original_image        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()  
        self.angle = 0

    def initLoc(self, pos, radius):
        self.pos = pos
        self.radius = radius

    def update(self):
        center = pygame.math.Vector2(self.pos) + pygame.math.Vector2(0, -self.radius).rotate(-self.angle) 
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(center.x), round(center.y)))            
        
    def turnLeft(self):
        self.angle = (self.angle + 4) % 360
   
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
cross1= Crucifix()
enemy_s = EnemiesStrong()
pos = cross1.rect.x, cross1.rect.y

enemy_s.initLoc(cross1.rect.center, 100)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(enemy_s)
all_sprites.add(cross1)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    enemy_s.turnLeft()
    all_sprites.update()

    window.fill(0)
    
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

I am not exactly sure what to try at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, what are you trying to achiev? That `EnemiesStrong` rotates around `Crucifix`?

Comment: Yes, I have it rotating but the Crucifix moves left off the screen while EnemiesStrong stays in place. I am trying to make EnemiesStrong follow the Crucifix.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the position of `enemy_s` in every frame depending on the position of `cross1`. Add a `updatePos` method to the `EnemiesStrong` class:

```py
class EnemiesStrong(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def updatePos(self, new_pos):
         self.pos = new_pos
```

Call `updatePos` in the application loop:

```py
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    enemy_s.turnLeft()
    enemy_s.updatePos(cross1.rect.center)                   # <---
    all_sprites.update()

    window.fill(0)
    
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

Complete and minimal example based on your original code:

[image]

```py
import pygame, math

class Crucifix(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                self.image = pygame.Surface((40, 40), pygame.SRCALPHA)
                pygame.draw.circle(self.image, "white", (20, 20), 20)
                pygame.draw.line(self.image, "magenta", (20, 0), (20, 40), 5)
                pygame.draw.line(self.image, "magenta", (0, 20), (40, 20), 5)
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (400, 400))
                self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
                self.px = 400
                self.a = 0
               
        def update(self):
            offset_x = math.sin(self.a) * 100
            self.a += 0.05 
            self.rect.x = round(self.px + offset_x)         
            
class EnemiesStrong(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)     
        self.original_image = pygame.Surface((40, 40), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.original_image, "red", (20, 20), 20)
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.original_image, "yellow", ((20, 0), (40, 20), (20, 40), (0, 20)))
        self.image = self.original_image        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()  
        self.angle = 0

    def initLoc(self, pos, radius):
        self.pos = pos
        self.radius = radius

    def update(self):
        center = pygame.math.Vector2(self.pos) + pygame.math.Vector2(0, -self.radius).rotate(-self.angle) 
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(center.x), round(center.y)))            
        
    def turnLeft(self):
        self.angle = (self.angle + 4) % 360

    def updatePos(self, new_pos):
         self.pos = new_pos
   
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
cross1 = Crucifix()
enemy_s = EnemiesStrong()
pos = cross1.rect.x, cross1.rect.y

enemy_s.initLoc(cross1.rect.center, 100)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(enemy_s)
all_sprites.add(cross1)

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *background.get_size(), (32, 32, 32), (48, 48, 48)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
[pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect) for rect, color in tiles]

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    enemy_s.turnLeft()
    enemy_s.updatePos(cross1.rect.center)
    all_sprites.update()

    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```